# How to replace Perl one-liner regex with Python one-liner?

Tags: python, regex, command-line-interface

I work on a project where *Perl* is not used and I would like to maintain consistency. That's why I'm wondering if I can easily replace this handy *Perl one-liner* with *Python one-liner*:

```sh
perl -pe 's/pattern/replacement/g' <<< 'expression'
```

This program reads from STDIN a line at a time, replaces all matches of regular expression `pattern` with the string `replacement`, and outputs the (possibly) modified line to STDOUT.

Comment: tried re.findall?

Comment: `sed` would typically be the usual replacement for that.

Comment: However, I would like to be able to use the Python regular expression engine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run `re.sub` with the `-c` command line option, but it won't be as pretty as the `perl` one:

```
python -c 'import re;print(re.sub(r"<pattern>", "<replacement>", "<string>"))'
```

If you want to get input from STDIN as well, you need `sys.stdin` and that also means `import`-ing `sys`:

```
python -c 'import re,sys;print(re.sub(r"<pattern>", "<replacement>", sys.stdin.read()))' <<< '<string>'
```

So, for example:

```
% python -c 'import re;print(re.sub(r"foo", "bar", "foobar"))'
barbar

% python -c 'import re,sys;print(re.sub(r"foo", "bar", sys.stdin.read()))' <<< 'foobar'
barbar
```

Answer (score 2):

A more modern replacement for Perl one liner would be Ruby, which is said by some to be Perl 6. For example:

```
ruby -pe 'gsub /[es]/, "X"' <<< 'expression'
```

Python, due to its reliance on indentation, is not suitable for one liner, especially when you need to use "if ... else ..." and such in the code.

Comment: Actually [Raku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/raku) is Perl 6 :)